# Prove$\frac{1}{PA_1^2}+\frac{1}{PA_2^2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{PA_n^2}=\frac{n^2}{4R^2}.$

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

> Let $A_1A_2\cdots A_{n}$ be a $n$ regular polygon with a circumscribed
> circle of radius $R$, and $P$ be the midpoint of the **inferior arc** ${A_1A_n}$.
> Prove that
> $$\frac{1}{PA_1^2}+\frac{1}{PA_2^2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{PA_n^2}=\frac{n^2}{4R^2}.$$

It's well known that $$PA_1^2+PA_2^2+\cdots+PA_n^2=2nR^2,$$ but this is useful for the present problem?
Please give a **pure geometric proof** without complex numbers or other algebraic methods.

Comment: Would you count a trigonometric proof valid?

Comment: @user35508 Why not consider an inversion transformation?

Comment: I don't know much about it. So can't help you there.

Comment: Have you looked at the proof of the "well-known" result?

Comment: Have a look [here](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1422994p8003721). They use, however, trigonometry as suggested

Comment: @Dr.Mathva Sir. I know the solution of such kind. But I believe there exists a geometric one. The result is too amazing!